# Como hacer un update de un registro en una tabla al hacer un insert en otra tabla

Tags: mysql

Necesito una pequeña ayuda tengo dos tablas en una misma base de datos. Necesito que cuando haga un *insert* en la tabla "viaje", se actualice el campo "*fecha_fin*" de la tabla "*viajes*" con el valor en "*fecha*" de la tabla "*viaje*", siempre que el valor "*viaje_nombre*" de la tabla "viaje"

He intentado hacer esto con un trigger, pero no veo la forma de que funcione.

**Tabla viaje**

```
CREATE TABLE `viaje` (
 `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `viaje_nombre` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `cantidad` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `fecha` date DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
 `de` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `tipo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=79 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf

**Tabla viajes**

CREATE TABLE `viajes` (
 `id` smallint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `descripcion` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `fecha_inicio` date DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
 `fecha_fin` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `url_fotos` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
 `url_mapa` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Este es el trigger que he intentado hacer, pero me está saliendo muy rebuscado.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `date_fin_viaje` AFTER INSERT ON `viaje` 

FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
set @ultimo_registro = (select id from viaje order by id desc limit 1);
set @viaje_nombre = (SELECT viaje_nombre from viaje where id = @ultimo_registro);
set @max_fecha = (SELECT MAX(fecha) from viaje where viaje_nombre= @viaje_nombre);
update viajes set fecha_fin = @max_fecha where nombre =@viaje_nombre;
END;
```

Espero que alguien me pueda echar una mano.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

para el trigger dispones de `NEW` que representa el nuevo registro, no necesitas buscarlo:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `date_fin_viaje` AFTER INSERT ON `viaje` 

FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
set @max_fecha = (SELECT MAX(fecha) from viaje where viaje_nombre= NEW.viaje_nombre);
update viajes set fecha_fin = @max_fecha where nombre=NEW.viaje_nombre;
END;
```

Debes tener en cuenta que si `viajes.nombre` funciona como clave de busqueda de viajes, puede que necesites que dicho campo sea unico, para evitar actualizar mas de uno de los viajes por error ( a menos que se pueda repetirlo y en ese caso todos seran actualizados)